# How to stop observing after activity destroyed?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-livedata

When I return to the activity the livedata remember the last value,
i need to clear the value when i destroy the activity.

How to clear the last value?

```
    translateViewModel = translateViewModel.of(this).get(TranslateViewModel.class);
    translateViewModel.getTranslatedText().observe(this, textToPlay -> fireTextToSpeech(textToPlay));
```

The problem is that when I destroy the activity and start him again, the livedata observe the last value of textToPlay.

i tried

```
translateViewModel.getTranslatedText().removeObservers(this);
```

but it is not working

Comment: Did you try resetting the value inside live data in onDestroy

Comment: translateViewModel.getTranslatedText().value = <Initial value>

Comment: where/ when do you call removeObservers method?

Comment: The most logical thing to do is onDestroy method, 
but it does not reset the value , and not solve my problem

Comment: Did you call it before super.onDestroy() ?

Comment: After      super.onDestroy();

Comment: The cleanest way of doing this is to put that `LiveData` instance in the `Activity`, not in the View Model. If a data is life-cycle dependent, storing it in the view model doesn't make sense. Also, AFAIK, `.onDestroy()` DOES clear the `ViewModel` in most of the cases except like configuration changes. So double check that your activity actually gets destroyed and recreated, before you "return to the activity". Normal back navigation doesn't destroy or recreate a new Activity, it simply resumes the activity in the backstack.

Comment: thank you , your tips helps me alot !